# Mybatis Custom Type handler: call FileInputStream.close() after query being executed

Tags: jdbc, mybatis

I am trying to implement MyBatis custom type handler for File using FileInputStream.

here is my code for setting:

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.LONGVARBINARY)
public class FileByteaHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<File> {
  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, File file, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException{
    try {

        FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());           

    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileByteaHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
```

}

My question is:

I can not close this FileInputStream at the end of this method, otherwise MyBatis will not be able to read the data from it. In fact, I do not know where I can close the FileInputStream. Is there a way to call close() after the query being excuted in MyBatis.

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE**

Thanks for Jarandinor's help. Here is my code for this type handler. and hopefully it can help someone:

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.LONGVARBINARY)
public class FileByteaHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<File> {

@Override
public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, File file, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    try {
        AutoCloseFileInputStream fis = new AutoCloseFileInputStream(file);
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());

    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileByteaHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public File getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    File file = null;

    try(InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream(columnName)) {
        file = getResult(rs, input);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return file;
}

public File creaetFile() {
    File file = new File("e:/target-file");    //your temp file path
    return file;
}

private File getResult(ResultSet rs, InputStream input) throws SQLException {
    File file = creaetFile();

    try(OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        int bufSize = 0x8000000;
        byte buf[] = new byte[bufSize];
        int s = 0;
        int tl = 0;

        while( (s = input.read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0 ) {
            output.write(buf, 0, s);
            tl += s;
        }
        output.flush();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return file;
}

@Override
public File getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    File file = null;

    try(InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream(columnIndex)) {
        file = getResult(rs, input);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return file;
}

@Override
public File getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLException("getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) is called");
}

private class AutoCloseFileInputStream extends FileInputStream {

    public AutoCloseFileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int c = super.read();
        if(available() <= 0) {
            close();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        int c = super.read(b);
        if(available() <= 0) {
            close();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int c = super.read(b, off, len);
        if(available() <= 0) {
            close();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
}


    public AutoCloseFileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int c = super.read();
        if( c == -1 ) {
            close();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        int c = super.read(b);
        if( c == -1 ) {
            close();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int c = super.read(b, off, len);
        if(available() <= 0) {
            close();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution isn't entirely correct. The AutoCloseFileInputStream read() methods need to return -1 immediately if the stream's been closed, and NOT call super.read().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a good way to close stream after query execution.

Method 1: 
read the file to byte []
(note: in jdk 7 you can use `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()));`) 
and use: 
`ps.setBytes(i, bytes);`

2: or create your own class inherited from `FileInputStream` and override `public native int read() throws IOException;` method, when the end of the file is reached, close the stream:

```java
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    int c = super.read();
    if(c == -1) {
        super.close();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Maybe you should override and `public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException` too, 
it's depends on the jdbc implementation.

3: you can change your `FileByteaHandler`: 
1) add list of `FileInputStream` field;
2) put opened InputStream to that list in `setNonNullParameter`;
3) add `closeStreams()` method, where you close and remove all InputStream from list.
And invoke this method after you have invoked your mapper method: `session.getConfiguration().getTypeHandlerRegistry().getMappingTypeHandler(FileByteaHandler.class).closeStreams();`
Or use mybatis plugin system to run above command.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the efforts. Great answer. Method 1: Since it is going to deal with some large objects, byte[] is going to be expensive. Method 3: It requires all the mappers know about the implematation of the handler. It seems a bit unexpected to the mappers.  (I have no idea about the plugin system. Where can I read more about it? Thanks.) Method 2: It seems the best option to me. Any downside you could think of?

Comment: 1. [`MyBatis plugins`](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#plugins)
But it's more complicated way than the override FileInputStream. 
2. `FileInputStream`. Problems can arise if the internal way to process input stream will be changed in future postresql jdbc releases. For example, using a FileChannel instead of invoke read for FileInputStream, or attempts to read after read return -1 (you should use closed flag in this case). I don't see any downsides. If my answer is not clear please let me know.